# It shows error when i run this code in andriod studio?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

flutter error how can i resolved this issue?

Error :

[image]

pubs.yaml:

[image]

Comment: pls post the error and yaml file  as text instead of image ..

Comment: Can you post your code, especially the import dependencies part. you might have imported 'dart:html' by mistake and need to delete it.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pictures of code are generally not helpful, you should post them as text instead. Also consider [including code or commands you ran to reproduce this error.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter pub get` in the terminal before running it on Android Studio.